# I want to end the while loop in python when both the conditions are false but it stops when only one condition is false

Tags: python-3.x

Here's my code, the purpose is to generate an array with 10 randomly generated 0's and 10 randomly generated 1's. While loops stops working when 'a' is equal to 10 or 'b' is equal to then and I am not getting equal amount of 0's and 1's.

```
import random
a = 0
b = 0

numbers = []

while (a < 10 and b < 10):
    x = random.randrange(2)
    if x == 0:
        numbers.append(x)
        a+=1
    elif x == 1:
        numbers.append(x)
        b += 1

print(a,b)
print(numbers, len(numbers))
```

Comment: @Avinash Even that won't solve it

Comment: I used or also but not working, still getting the same results

Comment: You just want 10 0's and 10 1's? Or are just trying something new?

Comment: Alright, after hours of efforts I found solution on my own. Btw, thankyou for your review.

Comment: @Zero I want numbers between range like x = random.randrage(10) will give me numbers between 1 and 9, it depends upon how much variables I will use

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this,

```
import random
a = 0
b = 0

numbers = []

while True:
  x = random.randrange(2)

  if x == 0 and a < 10:
    numbers.append(x)
    a += 1

  elif x == 1 and b < 10:
    numbers.append(x)
    b += 1

  if a >= 10 and b >= 10:
    break

  print(x, a, b)

print(a, b)
print(numbers)
```

But if you just want 10 0's and 10 1's then there are better ways to do that.

Comment: already did! I appreciate your work.

Answer (score 0):

It will work like this, I tried for couple of hours and found the solution.

```
import random
a = 0
b = 0
loop = True
numbers = []

while (loop):
    x = random.randrange(2)
    if x == 0 and a < 10:
        numbers.append(x)
        a+=1
    elif x == 1 and b < 10:
        numbers.append(x)
        b += 1
    if (a == 10 and b == 10):
        loop = False
print(a,b)
print(numbers, len(numbers))
```